# Auto login(skip login page) for ADFS and identity server 4

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, adfs

We are using identity server 4 and allows SSO with Azure AD. We recently added support for ADFS.

If we want to skip our login page for Azure AD, we can pass acr values like below:

```
acrValues = "idp:aad"
```

This works for Azure AD but if we want to do the same for ADFS, it does not work if we add **"idp:wsfederation"**. In this case it still shows login page and does not do auto login.

Anyone has any pointer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are connecting to AAD via OpenID Connect and this works because acr_values is an OpenID Connect / OAuth parameter.

WS-Fed is a different protocol. whr is normally used here.

**Update**

There is a [commercial product](https://www.identityserver.com/products/ws-federation) for WS-Fed.

If using ADFS 4 or above, you could use OIDC to [connect to ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios).

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use this with Identity server 4? If you can point out to any documentation.